# Unable to train Keras model though correct input shape

Tags: deep-learning

I am a newbie and have this Keras UNet model that I need to train.
https://github.com/Swapneel7/Deep-Learning-Keras/blob/master/UNet%20Keras.pdf
The input tensor does follow the required dimensions of 1024*1024*1.
Input:-

## Parse the mat into array

```
import scipy.io as sio
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
input1=sio.loadmat('D:\\Users\\svekhande\\tempx.mat')
TensorInput1=input1['temp']
TensorInput= np.expand_dims(TensorInput1,2)
print(TensorInput.shape)
```

## Model:-

def unet(input_size=(1024,1024,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
...
    .

## Training:-

model.fit(TensorInput, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=3)

## Error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error indicates I exceeded the bound so I  tried feeding smaller tensors (1023*1023*1), changing the network shape and resetting the graph but it did not work hence posting.

Comment: Need to pass label array too. In my case I passed the same thing.